# Replacing strings with special characters with linux sed

Tags: linux, bash, replace, sed, special-characters

I've read lots of posts to understand how to correctly escape white spaces and special characters inside strings using sed, but still i can't make it, here's what i'm trying to achieve.

I have a file containing the some strings like this one:

```
 JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dorg.apache.catalina.jsessionid=some_value"
```

and i'm trying to replace 'some_value' using the following:

```
sed -i "s/^\(JAVA_OPTS=\"\$JAVA_OPTS[ \t]*-Dorg\.apache\.catalina\.jsessionid*=\s*\).*\$/\1$DORG_APACHE_CATALINA_JSESSIONID/" $JBOSS_CONFIGURATION/jboss.configuration
```

- $JBOSS_CONFIGURATION is a variable containing an absolute Linux path.
- jboss.configuration is a file i'm pointing as the target for replace
  operations.
- $DORG_APACHE_CATALINA_JSESSIONID contains the value i want instead
  of 'some_value'.

Please note that the pattern:

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -D
```

Is always present, and org.apache.catalina.jsessionid is an example of a variable value i'm trying to replace with this script.

What's missing/wrong ? i tried also escaping whitespaces using \s without success,
and echoing the whole gives me the following:

```
echo "s/^\(JAVA_OPTS=\"\$JAVA_OPTS[ \t]*-Dorg\.apache\.catalina\.jsessionid*=\s*\).*\$/\1$DORG_APACHE_CATALINA_JSESSIONID/"

s/^\(JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS[ \t]*-Dorg\.apache\.catalina\.jsessionid*=\s*\).*$/\1/
```

is echo interpreting the search pattern as sed does ?

any info/help/alternative ways of doing it are highly welcome,
thank you all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo 'JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dorg.apache.catalina.jsessionid=some_value"' | (export DORG_APACHE_CATALINA_JSESSIONID=FOO/BAR/FOOBAR; sed "s/^\(JAVA_OPTS=\"\$JAVA_OPTS[ \t]*-Dorg\.apache\.catalina\.jsessionid*=\s*\).*\$/\1${DORG_APACHE_CATALINA_JSESSIONID////\/}\"/")
```

Note the bash expansion (in order to escape any `/` that may trip up `sed`) and the extra `\"` after `$DORG_APACHE_CATALINA_JSESSIONID` in order to properly close the double quote. Other than that your sed expression works for me and the above command outputs the follwoing result:

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dorg.apache.catalina.jsessionid=FOO/BAR/FOOBAR"
```

Comment: All the responses were useful, but this one is the most coherent with the example i provided, thank you very much. Just a quick addition, how to modify the script to replace first or second occurrence of the pattern ?

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean. If you use the 'g' modifier after the last `/` in the sed it will replace all occurrences. If you use a number instead of 'g' it will replace the occurrence corresponding to that number. e.g: sed 's/foo/bar/g' will replace all occurrences of 'foo' with 'bar'. sed 's/foo/bar/2' will replace the 2nd occurrence only.

Comment: As a generic info is correct. Thank you. I need a clarification on this: DORG_APACHE_CATALINA_JSESSIONID////\/  do i have to add as much / as the characters i have to escape in the variable value ?what's the meaning of having 4 consecutive slashes there ?

Comment: I redirect you to the man of bash: `man bash`. Look for the section called `Parameter Expansion` and `${parameter/pattern/string}` in particular. All is explained in there. In this case, the two outer slashes are part of the `${parameter/pattern/string}` construct, the two inner slashes are the `pattern` itself, `\/` corresponds to `string`.

Comment: Thank you so much, the secion in the manual is clear and your example too.

Answer (score 1):

You can use sed like this:

```
sed -r '/\$JAVA_OPTS -D/{s/^(.+=).*$/\1'"$DORG_APACHE_CATALINA_JSESSIONID"'/;}' $JBOSS_CONFIGURATION/jboss.configuration
```

Comment: If this answer helped you solve your problem, please consider marking it as "accepted", so users facing a similar problem in the future will be able to see it easily.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify a pattern that'll match the desired string rather than trying to specify it exactly.

The following should work for you:

```
sed -i 's#^\(JAVA_OPTS.*Dorg.apache.catalina.jsessionid\)=\([^"]*\)"#\1='"$DORG_APACHE_CATALINA_JSESSIONID"'"#' $JBOSS_CONFIGURATION/jboss.configuration
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sed 's/=\w.*$/='"$DORG_APACHE_CATALINA_JSESSIONID"'/' $JBOSS_CONFIGURATION/jboss.configuration
```